# How to organize the output of pd.ExcelWriter in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export-to-excel

I have the following code

```
etfc = [r'D:\Development\GD\AllDataSet_20230323\AllDataSet_20230323\2022_2023\PMV\KFC',
        r'D:\Development\GD\AllDataSet_20230323\AllDataSet_20230323\2021\PMV\KFC',
        r'D:\Development\GD\AllDataSet_20230323\AllDataSet_20230323\2020\PMV\KFC',
       ]

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pivottt.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

start_col = 1

for et in etfc:
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(et):
        for ofl in files:
            if ofl.endswith('Bins.csv'):
                uio = f'{root}/{ofl}'
                size = os.path.getsize(uio)
                if size > 20000000: # 20MB
                    year = re.findall(r'\d+', et)[-1]
                    strategy = re.findall(r'\w+', et)[-2]
                    df = pd.read_csv(uio,index_col=False,nrows = 500)
                    fs_col = [i for i in df.columns if 'FS_Bin' in i]
                    print(df.shape)
                    
                    start_row = 1

                    for i in fs_col:
                        qw = []
                        for j in df[i].unique():
                            sd = df[(df[i] == j)]
                            if ((sd.shape[0] > 0)):
                                qw.append({'File': strategy + '_' + year, 'Type': re.findall(r'(ed_(\w+))', ofl)[0][0],})

                        display(root,ofl,year,strategy, pd.DataFrame(qw))
                        
                        pd.DataFrame(qw).to_excel(writer, startrow=start_row, startcol= start_col, index = False)
                        start_row += 7
                    start_col += 3

writer.save()
writer.close()
```

This outputs the excel file in the following format.

| File | Type | blank | File | Type | blank | File | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PMV_2023 | ed_AAA_CR | blank | PMV_2021 | ed_AAA_CR | blank | PMV_2020 | ed_AAA_CR |
| PMV_2023 | ed_AAA_CR | blank | PMV_2021 | ed_AAA_CR | blank | PMV_2020 | ed_AAA_CR |
| PMV_2023 | ed_AAA_CR | blank | PMV_2021 | ed_AAA_CR | blank | PMV_2020 | ed_AAA_CR |
| PMV_2023 | ed_AAA_CR | blank | PMV_2021 | ed_AAA_CR | blank | PMV_2020 | ed_AAA_CR |
| PMV_2023 | ed_AAA_CR | blank | PMV_2021 | ed_AAA_CR | blank | PMV_2020 | ed_AAA_CR |

But i need the outfut vertically instead of horizontal. All Same files date vertically lined up. I tried placing start_col and start_row at different places but still didnt got the desired output. Please help. Thanks!
PS: there can be multiple files in the folder like AAA. BBB  etc. So the data of AAA vertically by dates then beside it data of BBB vertically by dates, like that

| File | Type |
| --- | --- |
| PMV_2023 | ed_AAA_CR |
| PMV_2023 | ed_AAA_CR |
| PMV_2023 | ed_AAA_CR |
| PMV_2023 | ed_AAA_CR |
| PMV_2023 | ed_AAA_CR |

| File | Type |
| --- | --- |
| PMV_2021 | ed_AAA_CR |
| PMV_2021 | ed_AAA_CR |
| PMV_2021 | ed_AAA_CR |
| PMV_2021 | ed_AAA_CR |
| PMV_2021 | ed_AAA_CR |

| File | Type |
| --- | --- |
| PMV_2020 | ed_AAA_CR |
| PMV_2020 | ed_AAA_CR |
| PMV_2020 | ed_AAA_CR |
| PMV_2020 | ed_AAA_CR |
| PMV_2020 | ed_AAA_CR |

Comment: Are you just trying to transpose your dateframe? `df = pd.Dataframe([1,2]).T` is "vertical" instead of "horizontal" (note the very last bit `.T`)

Comment: No,  if you check the folder path, there is year in between, so what the desired output is, each year output should be vertical, multiple files in a year should be horizontal,